# Python, YouTube API v2. Получения списка видео по имени канала

Tags: python, python-2.x, youtube

Как получить список всего видео (или максимальное количество, какое позволит API) по имени канала?

Направьте в нужное русло и поправьте, если я неправ.

Как понимаю, я сначала должен получить API-ключ для своего проекта https://console.developers.google.com
С учетом этого ключа я должен обратиться к API Youtube и получить JSON-объект, который необходимо распарсить на нужные мне элементы.
Пример обращения к API уже есть в одном из [вопросов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613903/youtube-api-v3-get-list-of-users-videos), но он для другой версии API. Буду благодарен, если кто-то укажет как построить запрос и получить адекватный ответ. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API, которое для этого нужно использовать – Youtube Data API, его текущая версия – V3. [В этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504899/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-uploaded-videos-for-a-certain-channel-with-the-new-youtub) правильный ответ рекомендует правильную последовательность действий. Продублирую на русском.

1. Получить id канала. Проще всего это сделать, зайдя на страницу канала и вытащив id из ссылки. Например, для канала [Moscow Python](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-OVMPlMA3-YCIeg4z5z23A) id будет `UC-OVMPlMA3-YCIeg4z5z23A`.
2. Получить id плейлиста. Для этого нужно сделать запрос к [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), в качестве id указав id канала из первого пункта. В ответе есть структура `contentDetails`, в ней – ключ `uploads`, в нём - id плейлиста.
3. Получить видео в плейлисте. Для этого нужно сделать запрос к [playlistitems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), указав playlistid (из второго пункта) и `part=snippet`. В ответе будет список разных параметров видео. Например, картинка, название, описание и id видео, по которому можно получить ссылку. Победа.

Для экспериментов рекомендую использовать [Youtube API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=ru#p/youtube/v3/) – можно по-быстрому разобраться в последовательности вызовов методов и их результатах.

Когда с этим будет понятно, останется перенести код на Python. Для запросов рекомендую использовать библиотеку [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Официальный SDK лучше не использовать без особой нужны – он очень многословный, сложный и неудобный.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! уже сам дошел до этого, правда, сразу не написал, ниже мое решение, вдруг пригодится кому-нибудь

Comment: Для спасибо есть кнопка "Принять". :)

Answer (score 1):

Выше [Lebedev Ilya](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208715/lebedev-ilya) уже указал последовательность действий для решения. Ниже представлю свой результат.

Для начала заходим на [YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#before-you-start), где описана вся последовательность действий, вкратце: заводим гугл-аккаунт, если у вас его нет, заходим в консоль разработчика, создаем проект, привязываем youtube-апи, получаем свой апи-ключ (в коде указал как YOUR_API_KEY).

Запрос к апи позволит получить только 50 результатов (ограничение апи). В моем случае я могу получить 50 последних загруженных видео канала. Или можно получать по 50 видео из каждого плейлиста, тогда нужно использовать схему из ответа выше.

uri обращения к апи следущий:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50
```

ниже представлен код, который берет из полученого ответ id, заголовок, превью и описание всех видео и фромирует лист

```
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
import json


def game_video_list(game):
    """ Get channel's upload videos| 50 limit"""

    youtube_link = {ссылка на канал вводится пользователем}

    # отрезаем id канала
    CHANNEL_ID = game.channel.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

    try:
        YOUTUBE_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={}&channelId={}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50'
        FORMAT_YOUTUBE_URI = YOUTUBE_URI.format( YOUTUBE_API_KEY, CHANNEL_ID)

        content = requests.get(FORMAT_YOUTUBE_URI).text
        data = json.loads(content)

        video_list =[]
        keys = 'id', 'title', 'description', 'preview'

        for item in data.get('items'):
            id = item.get('id').get('videoId')
            title = item.get('snippet').get('title')
            description = item.get('snippet').get('description')
            preview = item.get('snippet').get('thumbnails').get('high').get('url')

            values = id, title, description, preview

            if id:
                video_item =dict(zip(keys, values))
                video_list.append(video_item)

        return video_list
    except:
        return {}
```